# How do I inner join on the same table more than once using Nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I would like to achieve the desired `sql` using `Nhibernate` `QueryOver` (below) using the nHibernate code (below). The query generated does not produces any error, however, it does not do the `inner join` and as a result, the dataset return `null` for those properties using the `managerAlias` and `supervisorAlias`.

EDIT: I have included all relevant mapping/entity classes.

**how can I achieve this?**

**desired sql:**

```
select head.EmployeeID
        ,e1.EmployeeFirstName
        ,e1.EmployeeLastName
        ,head.SupervisorID
        ,e2.EmployeeFirstName
        ,e2.EmployeeLastName
        ,head.ManagerID
        ,e3.EmployeeFirstName
        ,e3.EmployeeLastName
from dbo.EvaluationHead head
inner join dbo.Employee e1 on head.EmployeeID = e1.EmployeeID
inner join dbo.Employee e2 on head.SupervisorID = e2.EmployeeID
inner join dbo.Employee e3 on head.ManagerID = e3.EmployeeID
```

I have the following code in my application:

```
                Employee employeeAlias = null;
                Employee managerAlias = null;
                Employee supervisorAlias = null;

                EvaluationHead headAlias = null;

                var query = session.QueryOver<EvaluationHead>(() => headAlias)
                                    .JoinQueryOver(() => headAlias.Employee, () => employeeAlias)
                                    .JoinQueryOver(() => headAlias.Manager, () => managerAlias)
                                    .JoinQueryOver(() => headAlias.Supervisor, () => supervisorAlias)
                                    .WhereRestrictionOn(() => headAlias.KRAApprovedDate).IsNotNull
                                    .SelectList(l => l
                                        .Select(h => h.EvaluationHeadID).WithAlias(() => dto.EvaluationHeadID)

                                        .Select(h => h.Employee.EmployeeID).WithAlias(() => dto.EmployeeID)
                                        .Select(h => employeeAlias.EmployeeFirstName).WithAlias(() => dto.EmployeeFirstName)
                                        .Select(h => employeeAlias.EmployeeMidName).WithAlias(() => dto.EmployeeMidName)
                                        .Select(h => employeeAlias.EmployeeLastName).WithAlias(() => dto.EmployeeLastName)

                                        .Select(h => h.EvaluationStartPeriod).WithAlias(() => dto.EvaluationStartPeriod)
                                        .Select(h => h.EvaluationEndPeriod).WithAlias(() => dto.EvaluationEndPeriod)

                                        .Select(h => h.ManagerID).WithAlias(() => dto.ManagerID)
                                        .Select(h => managerAlias.EmployeeFirstName).WithAlias(() => dto.ManagerFirstName)
                                        .Select(h => managerAlias.EmployeeLastName).WithAlias(() => dto.ManagerLastName)

                                        .Select(h => h.SupervisorID).WithAlias(() => dto.SupervisorID)
                                        .Select(h => supervisorAlias.EmployeeFirstName).WithAlias(() => dto.SupervisorFirstName)
                                        .Select(h => supervisorAlias.EmployeeLastName).WithAlias(() => dto.SupervisorLastName)

                                        .Select(h => h.DateCreated).WithAlias(() => dto.DateCreated))
                                    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(EvaluationHeadDTO)))
                                    .List<EvaluationHeadDTO>();
```

Mapping:

```
public EvaluationHeadMap()
{
    Id(x => x.EvaluationHeadID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(x => x.EmployeeID).Not.Insert().Not.Update();
    Map(x => x.ManagerID).Not.Insert().Not.Update();
    Map(x => x.SupervisorID).Not.Insert().Not.Update();

//other properties

    References(x => x.Employee).Column("EmployeeID").Cascade.None();
    References(x => x.Manager).Column("EmployeeID").Cascade.None(); ;
    References(x => x.Supervisor).Column("EmployeeID").Cascade.None();
}
```

---

```
public EmployeeMap()
{
    Id(x => x.EmployeeID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    //other properties
    HasMany(x => x.Employees).KeyColumn("EmployeeID").Inverse();
    HasMany(x => x.Managers).KeyColumn("ManagerID").Inverse();
    HasMany(x => x.Supervisors).KeyColumn("SupervisorID").Inverse();
}
```

---

### entities

```
public class EvaluationHead
{
    public virtual long EvaluationHeadID { get; set; }

    public virtual long EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public virtual long SupervisorID { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Supervisor { get; set; }

    public virtual long ManagerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Manager { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Employee
{

    public virtual long EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public virtual string EmployeeFirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string EmployeeMidName { get; set; }
    public virtual string EmployeeLastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EvaluationHead> Employees { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EvaluationHead> Supervisors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EvaluationHead> Managers { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    {
        Employees = new List<EvaluationHead>();
        Supervisors = new List<EvaluationHead>();
        Managers = new List<EvaluationHead>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping seems to be the culprit. A scenario, you are looking for, is one of the most usual.

So, if we would have `EvaluationHead` C# like this:

```
public class EvaluationHead
{
    ...
    // Employee
    public virtual Employee Employee   { get; set; }
    public virtual int      EmployeeID { get; set; }

    // Supervisor 
    public virtual Employee Supervisor   { get; set; }
    public virtual int      SupervisorID { get; set; }

    // Manager
    public virtual Employee Manager   { get; set; }
    public virtual int      ManagerID { get; set; }
}
```

The (xml) mapping of the `EvaluationHead` like this:

```
<class ...

 //<!-- Employee --> 
 <many-to-one name="Employee"   column="EmployeeID"   class="Employee" />
 <property  name="EmployeeID"   column="EmployeeID"   insert="false" update="false" />

 //<!-- Supervisor --> 
 <many-to-one name="Supervisor" column="SupervisorID" class="Employee" />
 <property  name="SupervisorID" column="SupervisorID" insert="false" update="false" />

 //<!-- Manager --> 
 <many-to-one name="Manager"    column="ManagerID"    class="Employee" />
 <property  name="ManagerID"    column="ManagerID"    insert="false" update="false" />
```

The fluent mapping

```
public EvaluationHeadMap()
{
    Id(x => x.EvaluationHeadID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(x => x.EmployeeID).Not.Insert().Not.Update();
    Map(x => x.ManagerID).Not.Insert().Not.Update();
    Map(x => x.SupervisorID).Not.Insert().Not.Update();

//other properties

    References(x => x.Employee).Column("EmployeeID").Cascade.None();

    // Instead of this
    // References(x => x.Manager).Column("EmployeeID").Cascade.None(); ;
    // References(x => x.Supervisor).Column("EmployeeID").Cascade.None();

    // use this
    References(x => x.Manager).Column("ManagerID").Cascade.None(); ;
    References(x => x.Supervisor).Column("SupervisorID").Cascade.None();
}
```

So, what we do have now, is:

1. fully mapped `EvaluationHead` (fluent mapping would be similar),
2. mapping of the `int` properties representing the ID columns and
3. the real references to `Employee` table (Employee, Supervisor, Manager)

We can adjust the query, like this:

```
var query = session
  .QueryOver<EvaluationHead>(() => headAlias)
  .JoinQueryOver(() => headAlias.Employee, () => employeeAlias)

  // alias without EmployeeID
  .JoinQueryOver(() => headAlias.Manager, () => managerAlias)
  .JoinAlias(() => headAlias.Supervisor, () => supervisorAlias)

  // this is done via mapping
  //.Where(() => headAlias.SupervisorID == supervisorAlias.EmployeeID
  //                            && headAlias.ManagerID == managerAlias.EmployeeID)

  // .Where instead of And
  //.AndRestrictionOn(() => headAlias.KRAApprovedDate).IsNotNull
  .WhereRestrictionOn(() => headAlias.KRAApprovedDate).IsNotNull

  .SelectList(l => l
      .Select(h => h.EvaluationHeadID).WithAlias(() => dto.EvaluationHeadID)
      .Select(h => h.Employee.EmployeeID).WithAlias(() => dto.EmployeeID)
      .Select(h => employeeAlias.EmployeeFirstName).WithAlias(() => dto.EmployeeFirstName)
      .Select(h => employeeAlias.EmployeeMidName).WithAlias(() => dto.EmployeeMidName)
      .Select(h => employeeAlias.EmployeeLastName).WithAlias(() => dto.EmployeeLastName)
      .Select(h => h.EvaluationStartPeriod).WithAlias(() => dto.EvaluationStartPeriod)
      .Select(h => h.EvaluationEndPeriod).WithAlias(() => dto.EvaluationEndPeriod)
      .Select(h => h.ManagerID).WithAlias(() => dto.ManagerID)
      .Select(h => managerAlias.EmployeeFirstName).WithAlias(() => dto.ManagerFirstName)
      .Select(h => managerAlias.EmployeeLastName).WithAlias(() => dto.ManagerLastName)
      .Select(h => supervisorAlias.EmployeeFirstName).WithAlias(() => dto.SupervisorFirstName)
      .Select(h => supervisorAlias.EmployeeLastName).WithAlias(() => dto.SupervisorLastName)
      .Select(h => h.SupervisorID).WithAlias(() => dto.SupervisorID)
      .Select(h => h.DateCreated).WithAlias(() => dto.DateCreated))
  .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(EvaluationHeadDTO)))
```

The JOIN is done for us by the mapping. In ORM world, it is the only way how to JOIN *(based on mapping)*. The rest of the query is mostly simplification

Comment: Kohler - I have updated my question with the changes you suggested, however, the `Manager` and `Supervisor` properties are not returned. I did a trace on the query generated using `SQL Server Profiler` and it does not do the `inner join` so it is safe to say that i am getting nulls for those fields because nHib does not created the joins. btw, I am using `fluent` so when u gave me the xml mappings, it got me paused for a while to understand it, I think I have gotten it though. while learning (still learning) I did not practice xml mappings.

Comment: You are almost there. The references must be mapped with the proper column names. Not all with EmployeeID, but with the columns representing the reference, i.e.: `SupervisorID`, `ManagerID`. BTW I used the xml mapping because your question was missing the fluent tag ;)

Comment: Great job! good luck with NHibernate. Do not give up. It is amazing tool and you will get lot of profit ... ;)

Comment: @RadimKöhler Why you must map that columns? `SupervisorID`, `ManagerID`

Comment: @Najera, we do not have to, you are right ;) In the question, I simply was not sure how to express that we can map the int as well as the reference. BUT, honestly, I DO that ALWAYS! Why? Because I can work with the ReferenceID directly.. without touching the reference at all. I can filter (WHERE), Order by and Project (SELECT). After using it few years I have to confirm: it is very hand, to have both approaches how to access the column ReferenceId... does it answer the question? ;)